# Computing an integral numerically to n correct significant digits

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, significant-figures

I have an assignment where I have to compute the following integral $$\int_1^{1.71}\frac {\cos \sqrt[4]{x}}{1+x\sqrt{x}}dx$$
to twelve correct significant digits.

What is the best method to achieve this when computation time is not a big issue? How do I know how many digits are correct?

Comment: There is no "best" method. You can use any standard method, such as Simpson's rule, to get the job done.

Comment: Welcome to mathstack exchange. What have you tried so far, what resources are available to you? The correct answer is $0.13382085109264$ but I just plugged it into mathematica to get it so it doesn't really help you.

Comment: Thanks! My biggest problem is how do I know I got a correct calculation up to n digits? Also, won't calculating that fourth root many times bring loss of precision?

Comment: You can of course write $\cos\sqrt[4]x=\cos 1\cos(\sqrt[4]x-1)-\sin1\sin(\sqrt[4]x-1)$ and $1+x\sqrt x=1+x+x(\sqrt x-1)$ and then employ the increased accuracy close to $x=1$ of $\sqrt[4]x-1=\frac{x-1}{(1+\sqrt[4]x)(1+\sqrt x)}$ and $\sqrt x-1=\frac{x-1}{1+\sqrt x}$. But this does not seem to influence the result, as to reach the desired precision, it is not necessary to sample the function at points between $x=1$ and $x=1+10^{-4}$ where the catastrophic cancellation would be relevant to the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider performances, you are correct with the problem of the square and fourth root.

Independently of the selected numerical method, I should let $x=t^4$ to make
$$\int_1^{1.71}\frac {\cos \sqrt[4]{x}}{1+x\sqrt{x}}dx=4\int_1^{\sqrt[4]{1.71}}\frac{ t^3 }{t^6+1}\cos (t)\,dt$$ Now, you face a smaller integration range and the second integrand is much closer to linearity than the first one.

You could even use series expansion around $t=1$ to $O\left((t-1)^{n+1}\right)$ and it would converge quite fast
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \text{result} \\
 0 & 0.13776738977500630815 \\
 1 & 0.13244166602060158949 \\
 2 & 0.13379101200456405488 \\
 3 & 0.13389678244323662667 \\
 4 & 0.13381286137858445987 \\
 5 & 0.13381750204286473434 \\
 6 & 0.13382176024778008614 \\
 7 & 0.13382093814245070512 \\
 8 & 0.13382078258061243158 \\
 9 & 0.13382085458575250985 \\
 10 & 0.13382085507917192293 \\
 11 & 0.13382085032932136977 \\
 12 & 0.13382085092985845912 \\
 13 & 0.13382085116591896269 \\
 14 & 0.13382085109375183538 \\
 15 & 0.13382085108748612023 \\
 16 & 0.13382085109326772813 \\
 17 & 0.13382085109291259286 \\
 18 & 0.13382085109256093758 \\
 19 & 0.13382085109263371344 \\
 20 & 0.13382085109264832238 \\
\cdots & \cdots \\
\infty &0.13382085109264158173
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: This helped me immensely! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The "best" simple method is Romberg integration. Let $M(n)$ denote the midpoint integration with $2^n$ intervals, $T(n)$ the trapezoidal integration and $S(n)$ the Simpson method. Then one can quickly check that $T(n)+M(n)=2T(n+1)$ and by Richardson extrapolation
$$
S(n) = \frac{4T(n+1)-T(n)}3=\frac{T(n)+2M(n)}3
$$
The Simpson method has error order 4, so that the next step in the Romberg integration produces the numbers $\frac{16S(n+1)-S(n)}{15}$ with error order 6 and so on.
$$\small
\begin{array}{l|lllll}
n& p=2&p=4&p=6&p=8&p=10\\\hline
0 &   0.1413610117349 \\
1 &   0.1357347551451&  0.1338593362819 \\
2 &   0.1343011488019&  0.1338232800209&  0.1338208762701 \\
3 &   0.1339410393737&  0.1338210028976&  0.1338208510894&  0.1338208506897 \\
4 &   0.1338509052773&  0.1338208605785&  0.1338208510906&  0.1338208510906&  0.1338208510922 \\
5 &   0.1338283650834&  0.1338208516855&  0.1338208510926&  0.1338208510926&  0.1338208510926 \\
6 &   0.1338227296181&  0.1338208511297&  0.1338208510926&  0.1338208510926&  0.1338208510926 \\
7 &   0.1338213207258&  0.1338208510950&  0.1338208510926&  0.1338208510926&  0.1338208510926 \\
\end{array}
$$

One can take the the next value down in the table as reference to compute an error estimate.

Answer (score 1):

Get a bound on the derivative on the domain. This in turn gives you a relationship with the Lipschitz constant L. This tells you how much point estimates can vary. So if you sample points in an interval I of size t, the error in calculating f(x) in I is at most Lt. Comment if more elaboration needed.

Note, this only works here as we can understand the derivative of your integrand.

Comment: I think this is too complex as it is just an undergraduate numerical methods class, but it still may be useful to someone else. I'm asking this because my professor is very nit-picky with precision and it's a graded assignment. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: In this case, I believe the Lip constant is bounded by 1, which says your error is at most directly proportional to the size of the subintervals you choose. So, I believe this means choosing intervals of the size of the error you need will do.